# Excel Power Query - Sleep or Wait Command to Wait on API Rate Limit

Tags: powerquery, m

In Excel Power Query (PQ) 2016, is there such a function that can insert a "SLEEP 15 seconds" before proceeding?  Not a pause, but a sleep function.

Problem:
I wrote a function in PQ to query: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0.  That function works fine, as designed.

I have a worksheet with 10K tweets that I want to pass to that function. When I do, it gets to ~60 or so complete and I get an ERROR line in PQ.  A look at Fiddler says this:

**message=Rate limit is exceeded. Try again in 11 seconds. statusCode=429**

I think if I insert a SLEEP 5 second (equivalent) command into the PQ function, it won't do this.

Help & thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You want [Function.InvokeAfter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt637158.aspx)

```
 Function.InvokeAfter(function as function, delay as duration) as any
```

Here's an example:

```
= Function.InvokeAfter( () => 2 + 2, #duration(0,0,0,5))
```

Returns `4` after waiting 5 seconds.

---

To answer a question you didn't ask yet, if you're going to execute the exact same Web.Contents call a second time, you may need to use the

```
[IsRetry = true]
```

option of [Web.Contents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260892.aspx) to indicate you actually want to run the web request again..