# Passing a "list" to a function call with the 'each' keyword

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

First things first, I will confess I am not an M or Power Query expert, though I do have some experience with Power BI.

I am trying to develop a stock portfolio that will track a customised list of stocks with their price history and other metrics. Part of my code is based on the following blog, due to the problem I am trying to solve:

https://datachant.com/2016/08/09/sentiment-analysis-power-bi-part-2/

I have the following function `getPriceMetrics` in my project that will take one parameter `Sym` and return the price metrics for an individual stock symbol:

```
(Sym as any) => let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("
        https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/metric?metric=price&token=ABCXYZ&symbol=" & Sym))
in
    Source
```

The parameter `Sym` is based on a "Query" that contains a list of stock symbols.

The function itself works well when I try to call it with one individual symbol. But I would like to run the function against a list of stock symbols - hence the blog above.

I think the solution offered in the blog would serve my purpose well. The only hitch is that I am unable to make the function call correctly with the `each` keyword, I think:

```
Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"Index"},
    {{"Data", each getPriceMetrics(_), type record}})
```

At this point, I get the following error.

> *An error occurred in the ‘getPriceMetrics’ query. Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Table.  Details:
>
>   Operator = &
>
>   Left = https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/metric?metric=price&token=ABCXYZ&symbol=
>  
>   Right = [Table]*

I would appreciate it if someone can offer any insight in how to supply a list argument to the function call when using the `each` keyword.

Edit: Here's my original approach, which is working technically speaking, but due to the limit of 30 API calls per second, some records are returned as null.

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Sikander\Google Drive\Docs\Finance\Investments\Questrade\FIRE_strategy.xlsx"), null, true),
Portfolio_Sheet = Source{[Item="Portfolio",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Portfolio_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Symbol", type text}, {"Company", type text}}),
#"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "getPriceMetrics", each getPriceMetrics([Symbol])) 
in #"Invoked Custom Function"
```

To counter this, I followed the approach suggested in the blog that will allow one to "cheat" this API limit, so to speak, by indexing and grouping, like so:

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Sikander\Google Drive\Docs\Finance\Investments\Questrade\FIRE_strategy.xlsx"), null, true),
Portfolio_Sheet = Source{[Item="Portfolio",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Portfolio_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Symbol", type text}, {"Company", type text}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 10), Int64.Type}}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Integer-Divided Column",{{"Symbol", "Ticker"}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"Index"}, {{"Data", each getPriceMetrics(_), type record}})
```

in #"Grouped Rows"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is happening because you are passing a table to your function instead of a fixed symbol. That table is the subtable of `#"Renamed Columns"` for a particular (single) `Index` value. Depending on what your table is, you might be able to get away with picking a single element from that table to pass to the function. Here's what that would look like if you took the first row `{0}` and `[Index]` column of each table `_`.

```
Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"Index"},
    {{"Data", each getPriceMetrics(_{0}[Index]), type record}})
```

However, I don't think there's a good reason to be doing `Table.Group` at all. If your "Query" is a list, then you can simply write the following to apply the function to each element:

```
List.Transform(Query, each getPriceMetrics(_))
```

If "Query" is a table with a column `[Sym]` you can replace `Query` with `Query[Sym]` in the above since a table column is a list.

Alternatively, you could add a customized column in the query editor GUI with the simple formula `getPriceMetrics([Sym])` and it will create a step with the following code:

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step Name Here", "Custom", each getPriceMetrics([Sym]))
```

---

**Edit:** This recent answer of mine has some screenshots of working with functions in the query editor that are relevant here as well:

[Power Query: how to add one to a column when a specific values appear in an other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488154/power-query-how-to-add-one-to-a-column-when-a-specific-values-appear-in-an-othe/61505574#61505574)

---

**Edit 2:** As pointed out in the comments below, the solution to this particular problem does not have to do with getting the syntax exactly correct but require a sleep functionality as I pointed to in this [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411616/excel-power-query-sleep-or-wait-command-to-wait-on-api-rate-limit?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "PriceMetrics",
    each Function.InvokeAfter(()=>getPriceMetrics([Symbol]),#duration(0,0,0,1)))`
```

Comment: Thank you, Alexis. I edited my question for clarity on what I am trying to achieve. I also tried what you suggested -  each getPriceMetrics(_{0}[Ticker]).  It does work partially in that it does not throw any errors but it is returning just the first ticker's metrics for each index/group. What I want is a way to loop through all the ticker symbols in each index group while being able to stay within the API limit. :)

Comment: To further explain, I am looking to achieve something like this, assuming there are 10 groups/indices:  Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"Index"}, {{"Data", each getPriceMetrics(_{0..9}[Ticker]), type record}})

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that you were trying to cheat the API. The `{0}` means the first row, so of course it's only returning the top one. Take that out and it will try to do the whole sublist. However, I don't think this will help because your situation and API limitations are fundamentally different. On the blog, the limit was how many messages you could send in one call whereas your finnhub limit is 30 calls/second. Grouping isn't going to help calls/seconds. You probably need a delay: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411616/excel-power-query-sleep-or-wait-command-to-wait-on-api-rate-limit

Comment: Thanks again, I tried removing the `{0}` like so `each getPriceMetrics(_{}[Ticker])` but I get this error:  Expression.SyntaxError: Token Literal expected. I will take a look at the speed delaying approach. :)

Comment: I misspoke. The difference here is that your function is written to take a single value, not a list or table (like in the blog). You could rewrite it to take a list but it wouldn't do anything to help your API limitations since, as far as I can tell, the API doesn't take batches of tickers.

Comment: No problemo. I did have a feeling that my function and the blog function are written differently and that is why I am not able to copy-paste that solution. :)

Comment: And thanks a bunch for walking me through the solution.  Function.InvokeAfter did the trick:  ` Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "PriceMetrics", each Function.InvokeAfter(()=>getPriceMetrics([Symbol]),#duration(0,0,0,1)))`. You made staying up this late worthwhile (nearly 2 a.m. here).  Woohoo.

Comment: I am going to accept your original answer as the solution, even though the solution itself is in a comment. Good night, amigo!