# Staggered API call in Power BI

Tags: rest, api, powerbi, dax

I'm fairly new to Power BI so forgive my ignorance if this is a stupid question. I've set up an API query to pull records from a 3rd party app, but the rate limiting of the app allows max 500 records per refresh, with some timing restrictions.

How can I set up my query to stagger the refresh, starting where it left off every time. So for example if there are 2000 records to pull, I'd want to stagger that to 500 (new) records pulled every minute until complete. I considered using incremental refresh, but there are no variables that group the data into small enough chunks.

Help? Can I provide anything else?

Comment: How about [Function.InvokeAfter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567584/passing-a-list-to-a-function-call-with-the-each-keyword/61567904#61567904)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411616/excel-power-query-sleep-or-wait-command-to-wait-on-api-rate-limit